# Regex : match word except specified word

Tags: regex

How do I use regex to match any word without show specified word

i want eliminate the word "you"

i have some word for example :

```
you eat
you handsome
you die
you will
you lie
and others
```

so, this program result :

```
eat
handsome
die
will
lie
```

Comment: Which lang/tool you're running?

Answer (score 3):

### PCRE approach

If you use **[PCRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions)** (perl compatible regex) you can leverage the **skip/fail** flags like this:

```
you(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\b(\w+)\b
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/wH5lR6/1)**

[image]

Then whether you access to the capturing group you can grab:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [4-7]   `eat`
MATCH 2
1.  [12-20] `handsome`
MATCH 3
1.  [25-28] `die`
MATCH 4
1.  [33-37] `will`
MATCH 5
1.  [42-45] `lie`
MATCH 6
1.  [46-49] `and`
MATCH 7
1.  [50-56] `others`
```

Quoting a paragraph of **[regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/pcre.html)**

> PCRE is short for Perl Compatible Regular Expressions. It is the name
>   of an open source library written in C by Phillip Hazel. The library
>   is compatible with a great number of C compilers and operating
>   systems. Many people have derived libraries from PCRE to make it
>   compatible with other programming languages. The regex features
>   included with PHP, Delphi, and R, and Xojo (REALbasic) are all based
>   on PCRE. The library is also included with many Linux distributions as
>   a shared .so library and a .h header file.

### Discard technique approach

On the ther hand, if you aren't using **pcre** regex then you can use an excellent regex technique (the best in my opinion) commonly named *discard technique*. It consists of matching all the patterns **you don't want** using a chain of **OR** and at the end of the chain use the pattern you are interested in and capture it:

```
discard patt1 | discard patt2 | discard pattN |(grab this!)
```

For your case, you can use:

```
you|\b(\w+)\b
 ^       ^--- Capture this    
 +-- Discard 'you'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use word boundaries and negative lookahead:

```
\b(?!you\b)\w+\b
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String sourcestring = "source string to match with pattern";
Regex re = new Regex(@"^you (.*)/$",RegexOptions.Multiline |
                                    RegexOptions.Singleline);
MatchCollection mc = re.Matches(sourcestring);
int mIdx=0;
foreach (Match m in mc)
{
   for (int gIdx = 0; gIdx < m.Groups.Count; gIdx++)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("[{0}][{1}] = {2}", mIdx, 
                         re.GetGroupNames()[gIdx], 
                         m.Groups[gIdx].Value);
   }
   mIdx++;
}
```

But you don't need Regex.

```
string[] words = new string[] { "you eat",
                   "you handsome",
                   "you die",
                   "you will",
                   "you lie",
                   "and others" };
foreach (var word in words)
{
     var result = word.Replace("you", "");
}
```

Comment: I think you mean this: `var result = word.Replace("you", "");` But there is a chance it might replace legitimate input, like `your`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use regular expressions, than this will work if you replace it with matcher group $2:

```
/(you (\w+))|(\w+ \w+)/g
```

http://regexr.com/3a8uk

Answer (score 0):

how when this problem like this ?

```
are you serious ?
are you ?
you are greatfull
```

and result :

```
are serious ?
are ?
are greatefull
```

Answer (score -1):

`/you (.*)/`

The matching group will be everything except the you at the beginning.

Comment: You didn't put in the start sign, so it can be anywhere.